# Programmatically tap a view

Tags: uiwebview, uitouch, uievent

Theres a new app on the app store called [AirWeb](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id770893993) that shows a web view on the TV and has a mouse that can tap within the web view. How can I do this also, tapping 1 view and sending the tap to a point in another view?

I have tried to see if I can fake a `UITouch` but everything I have found uses private frameworks and cannot be sent to the app store.